# Trigonometry Calculator Radians to Degrees and vice versa in .NET

Tags: .net

I'm quite new to programming and was unable to find an answer on these forums to the question I have.

I am using VB.NET and I want to put together a program that can convert Degrees to Radians (and vice versa), while the angle is calculated.

So in other words, there are two text boxes and  one button. The button is "Sin x." The text boxes have labels next to them: "Degrees" and "Radians."

Let's say you enter a value for degrees and click, for example, "sin x." From there, the program takes the value you entered, converts it to radians, calculates the sin of that converted value, and showcases it in the "Radians" text box. The idea is for you to also be able to put in a value inside the "Radians" text box, the program converts it to degrees, takes the sin of converted value, and outputs it on the "Degrees text box."

I succeed in getting degrees converted to radians, calculated, and put out on the radians text box, however I have hit a brick wall and am confused as to how I can have values be put in the radians text box, converted to degrees, and put out on the degrees text box.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Public Class TrigonometryConverter

    Private Sub btnSin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSin.Click
        Dim input, input2 As Double
        Dim output, Soutput, output2, Soutput2 As Double
        Const cfactor As Double = (Math.PI) / 180
        input = Convert.ToDouble(tbxD.Text)
        input2 = Convert.ToDouble(tbxR.Text)
        output = input * cfactor
        output2 = input2 / cfactor
        Soutput = Math.Sin(output)
        Soutput2 = Math.Sin(output2)
        tbxR.Text = Convert.ToString(Soutput)
        tbxD.Text = Convert.ToString(Soutput2)

    End Sub
End Class
```

tbxD.Text is the text box where "Degrees" values are put in and out.
tbxR.Text is the text box where "Radian" values are put in and out.

The program with the code above does not work at all, however, I can have the program work partially where degrees switch to radians, are calculated, and put out if I use the code below:

```
Public Class TrigonometryConverter

    Private Sub btnSin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSin.Click
        Dim input As Double
        Dim output, Soutput As Double
        Const cfactor As Double = (Math.PI) / 180
        input = Convert.ToDouble(tbxD.Text)
        output = input * cfactor
        Soutput = Math.Sin(output)
        tbxR.Text = Convert.ToString(Soutput)

    End Sub
End Class
```

tl;dr version: I have a program and want to have BOTH text boxes take in values input and put out CALCULATED values.

Any suggestions/solutions? Thanks!

Comment: You'd normally always do the trig in e.g. radians. So if they give degrees, you convert, take sin, then display output. If they give radians, you take the sin *first*, then convert the *output* to degrees.

Comment: Leave the `/ cfactor` in `output2 = input2 / cfactor` away. You don't want to convert radians to radians by dividing by a certain factor.

Answer (score 2):

This problem got started by bad UI design, you got stuck because of it.  Degrees and radians are of course strongly correlated.  If the user inputs the value in one box then you need to update the value in the other box.  Now it doesn't matter which box you use to calculate the Sine().  And don't put the result of the calculation back into the text box, display it in a Label instead.

Use the TextChanged event to detect user input:

```
Private Updating As Boolean

Private Sub txtDegrees_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDegrees.TextChanged
    If Updating Then Return
    Updating = True
    Dim value As Double
    If Double.TryParse(txtDegrees.Text, value) Then
        txtRadians.Text = (value / 180 * Math.PI).ToString()
    Else
        txtRadians.Text = ""
    End If
    Updating = False
End Sub
```

And much the same for the TextBox that the user can use to enter a value in radians:

```
Private Sub txtRadians_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtRadians.TextChanged
    If Updating Then Return
    Updating = True
    Dim value As Double
    If Double.TryParse(txtRadians.Text, value) Then
        txtDegrees.Text = (value * 180 / Math.PI).ToString()
    Else
        txtDegrees.Text = ""
    End If
    Updating = False
End Sub
```

Now calculating the sine is simple:

```
Private Sub btnSin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSin.Click
    Dim value As Double
    If Double.TryParse(txtRadians.Text, value) Then
        lblResult.Text = Math.Sin(value).ToString()
    Else
        lblResult.Text = "Invalid input"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you however, I am trying to avoid the use of Labels to display calculations for this program. I want calculations to be displayed in the textboxes so that users can input calculations in either box, click the sin button and have the values update in real time.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever, clicking the Sine button twice will of course produce nonsense.  But just write the code the way you want it, nobody is going to stop you.  Please close your question.

Comment: That's what I figured, this program is actually an exercise from someone who is teaching me. I'll bring it up to them that there's essentially no way to write this program how they want it given the limitations. Thank you (also, I'm not to sure how to close a question but I'll stop responding. Thanks)